# azure appfabric cache write behind functionality

Tags: caching, azure, appfabric, azure-caching

i tried to find some information on this but could not find any answer.

does azure app-fabric cache supports read-through and write behind?

thanks

almir

Comment: Support is available with Appfabric 1.1 caching: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377669%28v=azure.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you get a cache miss, you have to write the code your self to load the item into the cache, but this code is generally pretty trivial.

Likewise for updating the cache.  You have to update the underlying data store yourself and then update the item in cache.  Yet again, pretty trivial.